# How to style an "option" in jQuery Mobile multi-select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, customization, multi-select

I've added Close as an option, then I would like to trigger it to close the dialog if clicked. In addition I would like to set "display: none" for span with class "ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow", to make it look like a button.

Any advice?

http://jsfiddle.net/N5r4A/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the check-boxes:

```
#select-choice-0-menu span.ui-icon {
    display: none;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/N5r4A/7/

To close the dialog on selecting one of the options; you should REMOVE the multiple="multiple" attrib from your select tag... ie change

```
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
```

to

```
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" data-native-menu="false">
```

On a multi-select list; following will close the open dialog when "Close" option is clicked.

```
 $(function () {
  $('#select-choice-0').bind('change', function () {
      console.log('change in select', this);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
          if (this.options[i].selected) {
              if(this.options[i].value == 'closeMe'){                                
                  console.log('...closing Dialog');
                  $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
              }
          }
      }
  });
 });​
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5r4A/10/

Comment: Thanks you, but I want not remove "multiple" because I need it. I would like to add an option on bottom for closing the dialog (and styling it with your advice) because, if the list is too long, is not easy and intuitive go on top for do that.

Comment: Edited answer with how to meet your requirement.